# Using angular directive callback - updating a bower package locally

Tags: angularjs, bower, directive, pull-request

So i am using a bower package that is outdated. There is a pull request with code that fixes my issue however it has not been accepted.

The fix is only two lines and I tried changing it in my code, however its still not working.

How do I update the bower package locally?

https://github.com/onemightyroar/angular-camera/pull/19

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using bower if the package is deprecated. Instead download the package and move it outside of bower_components. This way you can edit the library to work, and bower won't touch the library anymore. However, if you make changes to the code inside of bower components, it still shouldn't be an issue and the problem might be with the two line fix you speak of.